# Split a string C#

Tags: c#, string, split

I need a little bit help.
I have a string

```
string source = "Mobile: +49 (123) 45678Telephone: +49 (234) 567890Fax: +49 (345) 34234234";
```

And I want to split in this:

```
Mobile: +49 (123) 45678
Telephone: +49 (234) 567890
Fax: +49 (345) 34234234
```

Thanks for your support
BR Thomas

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Where did you fail?

Comment: And? Why can't you? Have you tried something? Finding the index of `Telephone` or `Fax` is easy even though it isn't the fastest solution

Comment: Hi Thomas... it is usual to present an attempt at the solution 1st accompanied with the results and what your current problem is. thanks

Comment: Search for Regular Expression. There lies your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Matches()`:

```
string source = "Mobile: +49 (123) 45678Telephone: +49 (234) 567890Fax: +49 (345) 34234234";

string[] phones = Regex
                 .Matches(source, "[A-Za-z]+: \\+([0-9)( ])+")
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(i => i.ToString())
                 .ToArray();
```

**OR**

You can use `IndexOf()`:

```
string source = "Mobile: +49 (123) 45678Telephone: +49 (234) 567890Fax: +49 (345) 34234234";

var telephoneIndex = source.IndexOf("Telephone", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
var faxIndex = source.IndexOf("Fax", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);

string[] phones =
{
    source.Substring(0, telephoneIndex - 1),
    source.Substring(telephoneIndex, faxIndex - 1),
    source.Substring(faxIndex, source.Length - faxIndex)
};
```

Comment: Wow - very fast response. Thanks Roma - both solutions working. Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only because I'm bored

This function returns a dictionary of the three phone numbers.

```
Dictionary<String, String> ParseTelephones(string source)
{
    var tags = new[] {"Telephone:","Fax:","Mobile:"};
    var dict = new Dictionary<String, String>();

    tags.Any(a => { source = source.Replace(a, "|" + a); return true; });

    source.Split("|")
          .Skip(1)
          .Select(a => a.Split(":").Trim())
          .Any(a => { dict.Add(a[0], a[1]); return true;})
          .ToList();

    return dict;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time ;-)
I already know there are a lot of solutions